# woocommerce css load as dependency not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dependencies, styles, overriding

I am trying to enqueue my custom css AFTER woocommerce css but I don't know why it's not working.

it should be quite simple following the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

that's my code

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $deps = array( 'woocommerce-layout', 'woocommerce-smallscreen', 'woocommerce-general');

    wp_enqueue_style('header', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header.css', $deps, '3.2.6', 'all');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');
```

my custom css header-css is indeed loaded but before the dependencies.
I tried every kind of possibilities (with or without version number, with or without media parameter) without any success.

I found the same solutions in other sources like this one: https://bigwilliam.com/override-woocommerce-styles-semantically/

even though I can't use *get_stylesheet_directory_uri()* because mine it's not a child theme.

As you can see in the picture below, woocommerce styles override the *height* of the class 'logo', because it is actually loaded before and not after *woocommerce-layout.css*. I don't know what to do.

[woocommerce override my custom styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0iRn.png)

Comment: after adding the code you provided, try to delete cache from website and browser. it may be just cache issues

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately after deleting cache the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer!

my custom css is actually loaded AFTER woocommerce-layout.css and this is a selector cascade css rule issue (https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade)

this is my HTML

```
<body class="page-template-default page page-id-5 logged-in woocommerce-cart woocommerce-page">
   ...
   <img id="logo" class="logo" src="img/secondary-color-positive.svg">
   ...
</body>
```

the picture above shows that

*.woocommerce-page img* overrides *.logo* properties

that's not because my custom css is loaded before (as I was thinking) but because *.woocommerce img* is stronger than *.logo* as per **selector cascade css rule**

I got it fix just changing my css:

from this **.logo{...}** 
to **#logo{...}**

and now *#logo* is stronger than *.woocommerce img* as you can see below

[custom css override woocommerce-css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB1tG.png)